# How to make Webpack ignore components' templates?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using Webpack 3 in my Angular4 / Angular Material 2 / TypeScript project to bundle the js code. I'm trying to implement lazy-loading based on this sample: https://github.com/vsavkin/router_lazyloading
My project uses Angular Components with external templates (templateUrl instead of template). Webpack tries to include them in the bundle, but I would like to keep them external. How can I make Webpack stop bundling the templates?

My Webpack config:

```
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const ngtools = require("@ngtools/webpack");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    entry: {
        app: [path.resolve(__dirname, "out", "app")],
        vendor: [path.resolve(__dirname, "out", "vendor")]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out", "public", "assets", "js"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "/assets/js/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "@ngtools/webpack" }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ngtools.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
            mainPath: "./app.ts"
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor"
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            async: true
        })
    ]
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand it. If I use Webpack without AOT, I get smaller js files (still quite huge, but smaller than with AOT) and html files are loaded separately. Loading times are inacceptable. If I use Webpack with AOT, html files are bundled, js files become really huge, but loading times are great (as long as you have a good connection). Is there no way to get the best out of both worlds?